# How to run integration test on one controller?

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I was wondering whether it is possible in grails to run the integration tests for a single controller. For running all integration tests, i use

```
grails test-app -integration
```

how do i run the integration test for 1 controller whose name is SurveyController.

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please specify the full path of the integration test(copy the reference of it) class as below..

```
grails  test-app -integration path_to_integration_test.SurveyControllerIntegrationSpec
```

**Note**: Specify the test class name not controller name.

Comment: Sorry missed out the test class name. You should specify the integration test class of SurveyController i.e. SurveyControllerIntegrationSpec.

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
grails test-app integration: SurveyController
```

Comment: sorry that didnt work. please note i am using grails 2.2. do you know if this is a version issue?